# sbt docker:stage returns java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException error

Tags: playframework, docker, sbt, packaging

I am trying to follow this post http://www.ronaldcirka.com/blog/2014/12/06/deploying-play-framework-to-elastic-beanstalk-in-docker/
to package my play framework application for AWS deployment using docker and when I run:

```
sbt docker:stage
```

I get this error

```
[info] Done updating.
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
 ^
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1702)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
        at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2380)
        at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2422)
        at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$.com$typesafe$sbt$packager$docker$DockerPlugin$$makeAdd(DockerPlugin.scala:152)
        at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$$anonfun$projectSettings$8.apply(DockerPlugin.scala:79)
        at com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerPlugin$$anonfun$projectSettings$8.apply(DockerPlugin.scala:70)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:dockerCommands) java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
[error] \
[error]  ^
[error] Total time: 6 s, completed 19-Jan-2016 7:50:25 PM
```

Comment: I'm following [this](https://github.com/saaste/play-docker-aws-tutorial) tutorial and am having the same issue (it's step 3, and the command is 'activator docker:stage' but both commands produce the same error for me). Did you figure out what your issue was, @Dannyvas?

Comment: @Kreg to be honest I dropped it for now and changed the strategy. I am going to attempt this in a Ubuntu machine. Are you using windows as well?

Comment: I sure am. I was kinda hoping that wouldn't make a difference as long as I wasn't on an old version. I'm on Windows 10 though, so maybe I'm too new (docker specs list 7.1, 8, 8.1 & newer, but don't mention 10)?

Comment: From what I have seen it seems to be a windows machine issue.